# MacBook pro - External screen flickering after reconect

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have MacBook Pro late 2011. When I am at home, I use it with my external monitor, when I connect external monitor for the first time (after reboot), everything works fine, but when I disconnect the external monitor and reconnect it again, the external monitor starts flickering and external monitor screen starts turning on and off. The MacBook's default screen works fine. If I reboot macbook and then connect monitor, everything works fine until I disconnect and reconnect it again, then it starts doing that weird things again.

I don't want to reboot my MacBook after every time I disconnect external monitor... I am thinking, maybe I am not disconnecting the external display right. I just disconnect the cable. Should i be doing it another way?

Does someone have some experiences with that? Could someone suggest me any solution?

Comment: disconnecting hot wire is always challenging. So turn the external monitor off first then disconnect.

Comment: That does not seems to help.

Comment: is it 15" 13" or 17" because you might be able to reset the smc and pram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with non original power adapter. I've bought the original from Apple and the problem occurred no more...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, a lot of people recommended resetting the smc. and it seemed to work for a lot but not me. You should try it anyway, can't hurt. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295